# If statement in MS Access Expression Builder on Control Source

Tags: vba, ms-access-2003, expressionbuilder

I have an unbound textbox on my form I put on the control source `=Date()-[boundfield]` and it works fine it gives the number of days I needed but I wanted to have an If statement in this unbound field so using the expression builder I typed on the Control Source.

```
 =iff(Date()-[boundfield] > 120, "Max","not max")
```

But the unbound field always display `#Name?`. 
What might be the error on my code?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=IIf((Date()-[Adate])>120,"P","N")

This should work, put brackets as like this

Comment: Niduvani Somann Thanks bro!. It's My fault its just a type error I'm using '=IFF' insted of '=IIF'